The length of four-force
Recently, I'm reading the FeynmanLecture II_26 https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_26.html
It  says that the “length” of the four-vector is an invariant under what is called the “complete Lorentz group”—which means for transformation of both translations at constant velocity and rotations.
As for the four-force
$$f_μ = \gamma \Big(\frac{\textbf{F} \cdot \textbf{v}}{c},\textbf{F}\Big).$$
where $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1-(\frac{v}{c})^2}$.    F is the three-force.
v is the velocity of the particle.
So the square of the length of the four-force is
$$f_μf_μ = \gamma^2 \Big(\frac{(\textbf{F} \cdot \textbf{v})^2}{c^2}-\textbf{F}\cdot\textbf{F}\Big) = \gamma^2 \Big(\frac{v^2cos^2(θ)}{c^2}-1\Big)F^2 .$$
where θ is the angle between F and v.    F and v is the length of F and v.
But, while $\textbf{v} = 0$
$$f_μ =  \Big(0,\textbf{F}\Big).$$
$$f_μf_μ = -F^2 .$$
The square of the length of the four-force  is not an invariant. This is obviously wrong. But what am I missing here ?

The $\vec F$ appearing in $$f_\mu=\gamma\left(\frac{\vec F\cdot\vec v}c,\ \vec F\right)$$ is different from that in $(0,\ \vec F)$; in fact, the $\gamma$ ought to be a function of $\vec u$ and not $\vec v$ and so should also be different.

Do you mean that the velocity of the coordinate frame $\vec{u}$ is different from velocity of the particle $\vec{v}$  ?
